# python package import error on aws elasticbeanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, plotly-dash

I upgraded to dash2.0, the latest version and removed any references to `dash_core_components`.  Now, when I attempt to deploy on AWS ElasticBeanstalk, I run into an import error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'dcc' from 'dash' (/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash/__init__.py)
```

I have attempted to install the libraries on ec2 instance, but couldn't  do it successfully:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dash==2.0.0rc2`

Before I revert back to `import dash_core_components as dcc`, does anyone have thoughts on how I could make this work with `from dash import dcc` on aws elasticbeanstalk?

I am able to successfully run this locally. Local `python version : 3.8.5`

Python version on ElasticBeanstalk: `Python 3.7.10`

Comment: Did you install dash 2 on EB?

Comment: I have it in requirements.txt, dash==2.0.0

Comment: Can you ssh to the EB instance to verify it installed ?

Comment: @Marcin when I ssh and run `pip freeze`, I don't see dash installed. I get a warning: `DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support`

Comment: @Marcin dash 2.0.0 works only with python3.  I get the deprecation warning even though python3 is installed on environment.